# Read local text file using js/html file on on local machine

Tags: javascript

I've built a simple html page with javascript in a separate file, called on a button press.

I've opened the html file in chrome, and the path resembles: file:///home/tom/projects/index.html

The javascript needs to read a JSON file (file:///home/tom/projects/mydata.json) which is in the same directory, using a hardcoded path.

I'm really struggling to do this.  As I understand, this is because I'm using client side js (meaning I can't use the `fs` library for example), which is limiting my options.

According to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local), I can't load the file if I use the URL in the format: `file:///home/to....` as it gives me the error:

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: HTTP, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

If I start an HTTP-server, as the answer suggests, I can use server-side modules, but if possible I would like to avoid this.

I've noticed many answers that suggest using a dialog box like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications):

```
var selectedFile = document.getElementById('input').files[0];
function readFile (file_path) {       
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file_path);
    console.log(reader.substring(0, 100));
 };
```

but I can't make this work with a path in the form: `file:///home/tom/projects/mydata.json`

Is there a way to load a .json file from a `file:///home/to....` format URL using client-side javascript, with a hardcoded path (ie not asking the user to select the file from a selection box)?

Comment: This is a deliberate security restriction, to stop a user from being given, and then opening, a HTML page which then tries to read their disk. Run your page in a webserver (as that question suggested) then you can either load the JSON from a URL (e.g. something like `http://localhost/projects/mydata.json`) using JavaScript, or use a server-side language to fetch it and display it inside the rendered HTML. Either way will work, the first way is probably simpler and closest to what you've got now. It's always far better to serve HTML pages from a HTTP server, the way it's intended to be.

Comment: @ADyson thanks, I thought this would be the case, thanks for taking the time to explain this.   If you write up the comment as an answer I'll be happy to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a deliberate security restriction, to stop a user from being given, and then opening, a HTML page which then tries to read their disk.

Run your page in a webserver (as that question suggested) then you can either load the JSON from a URL (e.g. something like `http://localhost/projects/mydata.json`) using JavaScript, or use a server-side language to fetch it and display it inside the rendered HTML. Either way will work, the first way is probably simpler and closest to what you've got now.

It's always far better to serve HTML pages from a HTTP server, the way it's intended to be.